# Proper way to use GCM sender id in public manifest.json file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, push-notification, manifest, pushpad

I implemented the push notification functionality in my rails application using Pushpad. In order to make push notifications work in Google Chrome, I had to create a publicly available  **manifest.json** file. The issue is, my **gcm_sender_id** is publicly visible in manifest.json file.

Is there any proper way in ruby on rails to keep this information secure or any other secure way of implementing this.

Answer (score 2):

> gcm_sender_id is publicly visible in manifest.json file

That is absolutely correct and safe! The **GCM sender ID is public** and anyone can see it.

It's just the GCM API key that must be kept secret.